# Apache Web Server Virtual host not Working

Tags: apache, logging, web, server, virtualhost

I am trying to view logs directory on ui for Apache Web server.

So i am trying to establish a new virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf file and trying to give the document root to the logs folder.

```
<VirtualHost *:8083>
    ServerAdmin tecmint@example.com
    DocumentRoot C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Also i have given NameVirtualHost *:8083 and in httpd.conf i have Listen 8083.
After restarting the server when i hit localhost:8083 it gives 404.

Can u please help me i figuring it out.

Thanks

Comment: which line / path you have 404 in your log?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added directory block for your docroot and you have at least read permission on it.

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/"> 
Require all granted
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following VirtualHost configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:8083>
    ServerAdmin tecmint@example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/"
    ServerName localhost:8083
    <Directory />
        Require all granted
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```